# How to create alias for - minus sign

Tags: bash, unix, alias

I want to map the `-` to `cd -`

I've tried escaping it, w/ and w/o single/double quotes but neither of them seems to work.

`alias \-='cd -'` or `alias '-'='cd -'`
=>
`bash: alias: -=: invalid option
alias: usage: alias [-p] [name[=value] ... ]`

So the problem is that bash thinks I want to define an option for alias. (What would be a | Is there any) workaround for this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You must tell the `alias` command that you are not using `-` to specify an option. You do this by using `--` to indicate end of options, any following text is then treated as arguments to the command.

```
  alias -- -=cd
```

Comment: Also note that this is a common syntax for many GNU utilities: `--` terminates *parameter* processing, treating the rest as file names to be operated on.

Comment: I'm using `-` to `popd`, it works for me!